# What is documentLink from the readDocument function?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I want to get a document in a stored procedure by partition key and id.

I guess [readDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.rx.asyncdocumentclient.readdocument?view=azure-java-legacy) is a function for point reads.

> `readDocument(String documentLink, RequestOptions options)`

It needs a "documentLink" string as the first argument.

What is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.azure.cn/zh-cn/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.readdocumentasync?view=azure-dotnet),

> The format for documentLink is always "dbs/{db identifier}/colls/{coll
> identifier}/docs/{doc identifier}" only the values within the {}
> change depending on which method you wish to use to address the
> resource.

You can generate one in code

```
String documentLink = String.format("/dbs/%s/colls/%s/docs/%s", "yourDB", "yourCollection", msg.getId());
```

msg is the document